# Not getting output when I am using multiple `and` in if statement

Tags: python, regex

Below is my simple code for matching IP in python

```
import os
import sys
import re
str = "192.168.4.2"
match = re.search("(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})", str)
if (    match.group(1) <= "255" and match.group(2) <= "255" and
        match.group(3) <= "255" and match.group(4) <= "255") :
    print "yes IP matched"
else :
    print "no have not matched"
```

I am getting below output

```
no have not matched
```

I am not able to find why I am getting this output.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think you have to remove the ticks (") around your 255

Comment: @ThomasMey, the matched substrings are *strings*. `'192' < 255` isn't more correct than `'192' < '255'` is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, as Moses has pointed out, he has to wrap the match.group in a int(..) too for the comparison to work.

Comment: If you import regex, you can use this without having to do math checks. `r'(?|0?0?(\d)|0?([1-9]\d)|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5]))\.(?|0?0?(\d)|0?([1-9]\d)|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5]))\.(?|0?0?(\d)|0?([1-9]\d)|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5]))\.(?|0?0?(\d)|0?([1-9]\d)|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5]))'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are comparing `strings` which will compare by the first digit, for example:

```
print '4' <= '255'
```

will output

```
False
```

You need to type cast each of the operands to `int()` in order to compare digits

Answer (score 5):

You're comparing the matched string with another string, comparison is **lexicographical**, which is not what you want.

You should cast the output to int and compare with an int:

```
if int(match.group(1)) <= 255 and ... :
    print "yes IP matched"
else :
    print "no have not matched"
```

OTOH, if on Python 3, you may consider using the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) library:

```
import ipaddress

try:
   ipaddress.IPv4Address(addr)
   print("yes IP matched")
except ipaddress.AddressValueError:
   print("no have not matched")
```

Comment: There's a backport for `ipaddress` in Python: [py2-ipaddress](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2-ipaddress).